# Android studio - How to restart interstitial AD on onResume method

Tags: android, admob, ads, onresume, interstitial

My AD show up on start of the activity and when i pause it and resume it i want to show it again. Can't make it work properly so i would be glad for a full implementation into this code:

```
String adid ="000000000000";//Change this to your ad id
```

onCreate:

```
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(mainPage.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(adid);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("**************************")//
            .build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
```

then i have the displayInterstitial method

```
    public void displayInterstitial() {
       if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
           interstitial.show();
           pool.autoPause();
       }
    }
```

and onResume method

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    //here i want to restart the ad

}
```

Comment: It's simple `interstitalAd.load(request)` and then you may want to set listener too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **really** bad idea.

Admob have consistently said that they consider it a usage violation to show ads when the user does not expect it, such as on app start, on resume etc.

Continuing to do this will get your account banned.

Comment: Think about it hard, but if that is actually true then your app is not suitable for interstitial ads.